Flutter EventChannel doesn't return any values on IOS
I'm working on a Flutter project that utilizes the BluetoothCore package from IOS.
My goal is to receive information from the IOS side on things like: changes in the bluetooth adapter state (on, off, etc...) and new devices found during a scan.
Whenever I ask for an information directly using a Flutter Method Channel, I receive them on the Flutter side without any issues, but the same won't happen with Flutter Event Channels, which work more similar to streams.
Keep in mind I'm using Riverpod (with code gen) in the Flutter side.
Keep in mind BLE stands for Bluetooth Low Energy, it's one of 2 kinds of Bluetooth, the other one being called "Classic". The BluetoothCore package should work with both as stated in it's subtitle: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth
Lastly I'm using a real IOS device to simulate this, so I'm changing my bluetooth state manually as a normal user would do.
Flutter side:
First of all I set up a channel with a global variable like this:
const EventChannel cbManagerStateChannel = EventChannel("cbmanager_state_channel");
Next, I set up a provider using Riverpod:
@riverpod
Stream<int> cBManagerState(CBManagerStateRef ref, EventChannel channel) async* {
  Stream<dynamic>? cbManagerStateStream;
  int cbManagerState;
  try {
    cbManagerStateStream = channel.receiveBroadcastStream();
    debugPrint('Provider: cbManagerStateStream $cbManagerStateStream');
    await for (final state in cbManagerStateStream) {
      debugPrint('Provider: new cbManagerState arrived with value: $state');
      cbManagerState = state;
      yield cbManagerState;
    }
  } on PlatformException catch (exception) {
    debugPrint('Provider: PlatformException while receiving cbManagerState: ${exception.message}');
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint('Provider: Exception while receiving cbManagerState: ${e.toString()}');
  }
}

My idea was to "yield" the state coming from the IOS side, which is an int value, as stated in official Apple documentation. Even though I'm not using the enums I initially set up to better organize the states, I believe they are very helpful to understand what I was expecting:
enum CBManagerState {  // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbmanagerstate
  unknown, // 0      | The manager’s state is unknown.
  resetting, // 1    | Indicates the connection with the system service was momentarily lost.
  unsupported, // 2  | Indicates this device doesn’t support the BLE central or client role.
  unauthorized, // 3 | Indicates the application isn’t authorized to use the BLE.
  poweredOff, // 4   | Indicates Bluetooth is currently powered off.
  poweredOn, // 5    | Indicates Bluetooth is currently powered on and available to use.
} 

Moving to the UI/Views, this is what I set up initially:
class BluetoothState extends ConsumerWidget {
  const BluetoothState({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final cbManagerProvider = ref.watch(cBManagerStateProvider(cbManagerStateChannel));
    debugPrint('View: The value of cbManagerProvider ${cbManagerProvider.toString()}');

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const AppBarWidget(title: "Bluetooth"),
      body: cbManagerProvider.when(
        data: (cbManagerState) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text('cbManagerState: $cbManagerState'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        error: (_, stackTrace) => Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [Text(stackTrace.toString())],
          ),
        ),
        loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

As you can see I'm using a standard ref.watch, and both printing and showing the value as a piece of text on the screen. Even though I receive a value initially, it never updates afterwards.
Now moving to the IOS side, this is my AppDelegate.swift code:

import UIKit
import Flutter
import CoreBluetooth
import os.log

var cbManagerState: Int = 0

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            let controller = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
            
            let bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager = BluetoothManager()
            
            let cbManagerStateChannel = FlutterEventChannel(name: "cbmanager_state_channel", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)

            let cbManagerStateController: CBManagerStateController = CBManagerStateController()
            
            cbManagerStateChannel.setStreamHandler(cbManagerStateController)
            
            GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
            return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        }
}

class BluetoothManager: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    
    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager
    
    override init() {
        self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: nil, queue: nil)
        super.init()
        centralManager.delegate = self
    }
    
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        let arguments : Int = central.state.rawValue
        cbManagerState = arguments
        print("IOS: cbManagerState updated state is:", cbManagerState)
    }
}

class CBManagerStateController: NSObject, FlutterStreamHandler {
    
    override init() {
        print("IOS: CBManagerStateController is instantiated")
    }
    
    func onListen(withArguments arguments: Any?, eventSink events: @escaping FlutterEventSink) -> FlutterError? {
        print("IOS: centralManager state in the controller is:", cbManagerState)
        events(cbManagerState)
        return nil
    }
    
    func onCancel(withArguments arguments: Any?) -> FlutterError? {
        return nil
    }
}

Since I have very little knowledge of Swift, I simply attempted to create a global variable, which would be updated, every time the bluetooth adapter state changes.
When the app is first started I do see prints from the IOS side such as:

"print("IOS: CBManagerStateController is instantiated")"
"print("IOS: cbManagerState updated state is:", someValue)" // 4, 5, etc

And more importantly, when I manually change my bluetooth from off to on I see:

"print("IOS: cbManagerState updated state is:", cbManagerState)"

This means the centralManagerDidUpdateState method is being called on demand, it is most likely updating the value accordingly, yet this doesn't translate to it sending a new valeu through the sink/stream.
My theory is it's something related to how the variable's value is allocated in memory. Very frequently in Flutter you need to copy objects instead of simply changing a property, because in order for the UI to react it needs to know the object change, so creating a new one is the easiest thing.
Since I'm only updating the value of this variable, it is not enough for the sink to understand this as a new event and pass it on to Flutter.
I'm fully available to fill any missing gaps in this explanation.

You don't have any code that tells your CBManagerStateController to emit an event when the global cbManagerState variable changes. Rather than use a global, why don't you pass your CBManagerStateController instance to your BluetoothManager and then the manager can call a method in the controller when the state changes.

Hi @Paulw11 thanks for answering. If I understood correctly my BluetoothManager class should now receive the very same instance of CBManagerStateController which I've already created in AppDelegate, right? So for this I probably need to change it's constructor (maybe in Swift it's called something else). I'll give it a try and answer here later.

Yes, you would pass the instance via the initialiser

@Paulw11 thanks for your help, I posted a full answer referencing you.

I fixed this issue using @Paulw11's advice, these are the core changes:
Within my AppDelegate class I used the instance of CBManagerStateController I already had:
let cbManagerStateController: CBManagerStateController = CBManagerStateController()

And passed it to the constructor of my BluetoothManager's class like:
let bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager = BluetoothManager(cbManagerStateController: cbManagerStateController)

For this I naturally had to change the BluetoothManager class implementation itself like this:
Added this private variable:
private let cbManagerStateController: CBManagerStateController

Changed the constructor like this:
init(cbManagerStateController: CBManagerStateController) {
  ...other code
  self.cbManagerStateController = cbManagerStateController
  super.init()
}

I also updated my centralManagerDidUpdateState like this:
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    let arguments : Int = central.state.rawValue
    cbManagerStateController.eventSink?(arguments)
    print("IOS: centralManagerDidUpdateState is:", arguments)
}

And finally used the FlutterEventSink properly within the CBManagerStateController class like this:
class CBManagerStateController: NSObject, FlutterStreamHandler {
    
    var eventSink: FlutterEventSink?
    
    func onListen(withArguments arguments: Any?, eventSink: @escaping FlutterEventSink) -> FlutterError? {
        print("IOS: Controller: CBManagerStateController onListen was called")
        self.eventSink = eventSink
        return nil
    }
    
    func onCancel(withArguments arguments: Any?) -> FlutterError? {
        print("IOS: Controller: CBManagerStateController onCancel was called")
        eventSink = nil
        return nil
    }
}

No changes were made to the Flutter side, the provider works just fine now!
As I change my bluetooth adapter on and off, I immediately see changes in my UI by watching the provider with a ref.watch.
